# How to transfer more than 65536 rows from excel to Access (Both Version 2010)

Tags: database, excel, ms-access, import, export

I have the following code to transfer some rows from Excel to an Access Data Base, then it export from Access to a .txt file. The problem is that when I export it to Access, it only exports 65536 rows. Is there a way to fix it?

```
 Sub Mailing_Recebido()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim Caminho As String
    Dim A As Object

    Range("i27").Value = "Inicio da Exportação..."

    Range("BJ18").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=CELL(""nome.arquivo"")"
    Range("BJ18").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("BJ18"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
        :="[", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Range("BK18").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Caminho = Range("bj18").Value

    Sheets("Mailing_Recebido").Select

    Range("a5").Select
    i = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Sheets("Plan1").Select
    Range("BO5").Value = i

    Range("BO3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTA(Mailing_Recebido!R[2]C[-66]:R[1048573]C[-66])"

    ActiveSheet.Calculate


    'Range("BN3").Select
    Range("BM26").Select
    Range("BM26").Value = Range("BO8").Value


    Set A = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    A.Visible = False
    A.OpenCurrentDatabase (Caminho + "\Cria_Mailing.mdb")
    A.DoCmd.RunMacro "Executar"

    'Range("bk22").Value = FileLen(Caminho + "\" + Range("c32").Value)
    Calculate

    'Call XTo_txt
    Range("i27").Value = "Exportação Completada..."



   End Sub
```

The Function "Exportar" calls 2 new functions "Importar" then "Exportar" here are them:

```
Option Compare Database


Function exporta()


    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim caminho As String
    Dim NomeArq As String

    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("NOMEBASE")


    caminho = rs.Fields(0).Value + "\" + rs.Fields(1).Value



    DoCmd.TransferText acExportFixed, "Mailing_Envio", "BASE", caminho



End Function


Function importa()

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim inicio As String
    Dim fim As String



'DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , _
    '"NOMEBASE", Application.CurrentProject.Path() + "\Abre_Envio_Novo_Layout.xlsm", True, "Plan1!BJ25:BM26"

 DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, _
    "NOMEBASE", Application.CurrentProject.Path() + "\Abre_Envio_Novo_Layout.xlsm", True, "Plan1!BJ25:BM26"


   ' TypeExcel12



    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("NOMEBASE")

    inicio = rs.Fields(2).Value
    fim = rs.Fields(3).Value


'DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , _
    '"BASE", Application.CurrentProject.Path() + "\Abre_Envio_Novo_Layout.xlsm", True, "Mailing_Recebido!A:AX"
    ' + inicio + ":" + fim


DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, _
    "BASE", Application.CurrentProject.Path() + "\Abre_Envio_Novo_Layout.xlsm", True, "Mailing_Recebido!A:AX"
    ' + inicio + ":" + fim


    rs.Close

End Function
```

No one have a clue? =(

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention! Both 2010.

Comment: On Access, if I check the database on acess it receives only 65536 rows, so it only exports 65536 lines to the .txt file.

Comment: I'll do it, thanks! "Executar" calls 2 functions "Importar" then "Exeportar" I'll edit the question with them.

Comment: Not sure why this was marked as duplicate of an "Answered" question. The "answered" question that is linked is not the same. This question has a specified Range and the linked question answer does not. This makes a difference; specifying a range restricts to 65536 rows - that's the question that needs answering.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to import an .xls file even if it was created using Excel 2010? Because the limit on max number of rows is 65536 in *all* .xls files. You could try a .xlsx file to see if it imports only 65536 rows.

Comment: Yes, I tried both extensions and both have this limit..